# Quitar ciertos caracteres especiales de un String Java

Tags: java, csv

Estoy leyendo un archivo CSV, pero a la hora de visualizar la informacion esta me aparece asi:

```
U S  $ 1   =   $ 7 9 1   T A S A    D E    C A M B I O
```

He probado usando un replaceAll

```
replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]","");
```

Dandome el siguiente resultado

```
US  Tasa de cambio
```

, me quita los espacios de mas, pero tambien ciertos caracteres especiales, la idea es que no me quite los signos

```
$ - / \ " . ,
```

ni los numeros que vengas despues,palabras con acentos, ya que necesito esa informacion para procesarla

Comment: ¿El resultado esperado es `US $1 = $791 TASA DE CAMBIO`? Todo separado por un espacio o ningún espacio?

Answer (score 0):

Pues, lo primero que se me ocurre, rudimentario como es, sería identificar lo que debe quedar como espacio, limpiar luego los espacios innecesarios y luego cambiar los lugares identificados como espacio y hacerlos espacios:

```
  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
      String inputText = "U S  $ 1   =   $ 7 9 1   T A S A    D E    C A M B I O";
      inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\s{3}",".");
      inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\s+","");
      inputText = inputText.replaceAll("\\."," ");
      System.out.println(inputText);
    }
  }
```